# Why fieldStorage is empty in Jython Servlet post request

Tags: java, python, servlets, jython

I have created a simple jython servlet file with a doPost Method. I'm trying to post a form but in the servlet I'm not getting the post values. Below is the piece of code I'm trying with.

```
Test.html
---------
<form action='Index.py' method='post'>
   <input type="text" name="username" value="ifti" />
   <input type="text" name="password" value="ifti1233" />
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Index.py
--------

from javax.servlet.http import HttpServlet
import cgi, cgitb, os, sys, shutil
import urllib2
import org.python.util.PyFilter

cgitb.enable();

class Index(HttpServlet):
    def doPost(self,req,res):   
        res.setContentType("text/html")
        form = cgi.FieldStorage()
        out = res.getWriter()
        keys = form.keys()
        keys.sort()
        pageContent = "<br />number of keys: "+str(len(keys))
        for key in keys:
               pageContent += fieldStorage[ key ].value
        out.println(pageContent)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cgi.FieldStorage` expects its input from either the standard input of the process or its environment. This is how the web server and CGI request handler cooperate to serve HTTP requests.

Servlets, however, use a different protocol for transferring the raw HTTP request from web server to request handler, and the HTTP request is not readily available to be read from the standard input/environment. That's why your `cgi.FieldStorage()` does not detect any post fields. Instead, the processed request is provided in a `HttpServletRequest` object passed to `doPost()`. You can call the methods on `HttpServletRequest` to obtain the post fields and headers, e.g.

```
import cgi
from pprint import pformat
from javax.servlet.http import HttpServlet

class Index(HttpServlet):
    def doPost(self,req,res):
        res.setContentType("text/html")
        out = res.getWriter()

        out.println('<strong>Headers</strong>')

        headers = {}
        for n in req.headerNames:
                headers[n] = req.getHeader(n)
        out.println('<pre>')
        out.println(pformat(headers))
        out.println('</pre><br />')

        out.println('<strong>Form fields</strong>')

        # get the POST data fields
        form = {}
        for field in req.parameterMap:
                form[field] = list(req.parameterMap[field])

#        # Alternative - if you *really* want a FieldStorage object, construct
#        # one from the request body, headers and faked environment variables.
#        # N.B. assumes that the request body is one line of POST data only.
#        from StringIO import StringIO
#        request_body = req.reader.readLine()
#        form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=StringIO(request_body),
#                    headers=headers,
#                    environ={'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
#                             'CONTENT_LENGTH': len(request_body)})

        out.println('<pre>%s</pre><br />' % pformat(form))
```

Using your test form you should see output similar to this:

```
Headers

{'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'accept-language': 'en-au,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
 'connection': 'keep-alive',
 'content-length': '45',
 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'host': 'localhost:8080',
 'referer': 'http://localhost:8080/jython-servlets/test.html',
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0'}

Form fields

{'password': ['ifti1233'], 'Submit': ['Submit'], 'username': ['ifti']}
```